# Feasibility of old .NET 3.5 webservices on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

We have some old webservices that target .NET 3.5, and are running in IIS6 on 2003 Server boxes.  We would like to migrate to IIS 7.5 on 2008 R2 and take advantage of the Integrated Pipeline in IIS 7.  This brings me to my list of questions and I would appreciate input on any of them:

1. Is there any situation in which we might have to migrate the service
   projects to target .NET 4 in order for them to work in the new
   environment?
2. If we don't have to change the services, and we keep the Install
   package for the services targetting ASP .NET 2, will the Integrated
   Pipeline apply to the .NET 2 app pool?
3. If the answer to #2 is no, would the Integrated Pipeline work with
   the services if we target ASP .NET 4 in the install (but don't
   change the target framework in the service projects)?

Basically, I was informed that the designer of these services (who can no longer be reached for comment) really did not want to migrate to IIS 7, but researching this on the web, I see no reason for his hesitation.